# How to check if file has valid JSON syntax in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, try-catch, powershell-3.0

I am trying to write a powershell script that reads a file and prints "true" if it is a valid JSON file. I am using Powershell v3.0 and this is what I have right now :

```
$text = Get-Content .\filename.txt -Raw 
$powershellRepresentation = $text | ConvertFrom-Json
```

How do I check the return code? I mean I want something like this :

```
if(file not a JSON file){
 Write-Host "not JSON"
}
else{
 Write-Host "True"
}
```

Comment: I can do it by catching the exception. But is there any other way?

Comment: In PowerShell 6.0, Test-Json Cmdlet is available. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE 2021: PowerShell 6 and newer versions**

PowerShell 6 brings a brand new `Test-Json` cmdlet. [Here is the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-7.1).

You can simply pass the raw file content directly to the `Test-Json` cmdlet.

```
$text = Get-Content .\filename.txt -Raw

if ($text | Test-Json) {
    $powershellRepresentation = ConvertFrom-Json $text -ErrorAction Stop;
    Write-Host "Provided text has been correctly parsed to JSON";
} else {
    Write-Host "Provided text is not a valid JSON string";
}
```

**PowerShell 5 and earlier versions**

There is no `Test-Json` cmdlet in these versions, so the best way is to put your `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet inside a `try ... catch` block

```
try {
    $powershellRepresentation = ConvertFrom-Json $text -ErrorAction Stop;
    $validJson = $true;
} catch {
    $validJson = $false;
}

if ($validJson) {
    Write-Host "Provided text has been correctly parsed to JSON";
} else {
    Write-Host "Provided text is not a valid JSON string";
}
```

Comment: saved my life. trying to figure out an issue where PS4 didn't convert JSON to PSObject with `invoke-restMethod`. you win the internet.

Comment: Unfortunately, {"a":1,"a":2} passes this test whereas it has duplicate property keys. Most of the parsers don't complain and usually consider the latest property .. However, there is definitely a problem.

Comment: I tried to repeat this functionality with the in-built `Test-Json` with `if(Test-Json $text) {...}`, but I kept getting `Test-Json: Cannot parse the JSON` errors when the file included stuff like `egg` or `{{}`. This solution worked perfectly! Not sure why I couldn't get `Test-Json` to work...

Comment: FWIW... test-json was added in PS 6.1  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-6

Comment: I included the PS6 solution. Keep in mind that doesn't work for OP since he's on PS3

Answer (score 7):

If you encounter this question and can use PowerShell 6 or later, there is now a Test-Json cmdlet. It can also not just validate that it's valid JSON, but that it conforms to a particular JSON schema using the `-Schema` param.

### Example

```
$isValid = Get-Content .\filename.txt -Raw | Test-Json 

if($isValid){
 Write-Host "not JSON"
}
else{
 Write-Host "True"
}
```

### ARM Template Warning

A note for users looking to validate an ARM template via `-Schema` (I can't imagine a more perfect use case). At the time of writing, there are one or more bugs in the underlying library `Test-Json` uses for validation, NJsonSchema, and it is not possible to validate an ARM template.

#### GitHub Issues

- [PowerShell Issue #9560](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9560)
- [NJsonSchema Issue #588](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/588)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it exists an other solution than catching the exception using `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Answer (score 1):

ConvertFrom-JSON would work but only for a JSON object < 2MB in size.
For higher you can use JavaScriptSerializer class

```
try
{
    $jsser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    $jsser.MaxJsonLength = $jsser.MaxJsonLength * 10
    $jsser.RecursionLimit = 99    

    $outObject = $jsser.DeserializeObject($json)
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error converting $text to JSON"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ConvertFrom-Json shd be the appropriate way to go.
Test-Json unfortunately has alot of known unsupported JSON Types.
I.E. it cannot parse Json-Arrays or Primitives properly leading to falsely assuming it has wrong JSON-Syntax.