# Azure Batch Needs to be Updated to PowerShell Version 7+

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I am running a Custom Activity in Azure Data Factory.  We are using the Test-Json command to validate JSON data against a schema.  This command works perfectly find in PowerShell version 7+ but will fail in version 5.1.

For testing purposes, if I run the below command (directly from the Microsoft documentation) it fails when using the Custom Activity in Data Factory.

"{'name': 'Ashley', 'age': 25}" | Test-Json

If I run the below command, it show that we are using PowerShell version 5.1.

$PSVersionTable

Is there anyway to upgrade to version 7.1 so these batch file will process successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Two potential options:

**Modify your task to use `ConvertFrom-Json` with a try-catch block instead of `Test-Json`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17170800/2467540)**.

As you've already pointed out, `Test-Json` comes with PowerShell 7.1 (part of [PowerShell Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/#whats-the-difference-between-windows-powershell-and-powershell-core)), but it doesn't come with PowerShell 5.1 (part of [Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/windows-powershell-system-requirements?view=powershell-7.1)), which many Windows images have installed by default. `ConvertFrom-Json`, however, does come with PowerShell 5.1 and can provide the  same functionality as `Test-Json` with a few tweaks.

**Install PowerShell Core 7.1 as a [start task](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/jobs-and-tasks#start-task), and then invoke your command as normal**.

The start task syntax to complete this installation would be `cmd /c "powershell.exe -c "iex ""&" { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1) } -UseMSI -Quiet"""`, based off the one-liner described [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/how-to-install-and-update-powershell-6-one-liner/m-p/364948) and modified to fit the Batch syntax described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/jobs-and-tasks#tasks). This will install the latest version of PowerShell Core, which will have `Test-Json` included. When creating tasks, be sure to invoke PowerShell Core using `pwsh.exe`, and not `powershell.exe`, which is for Windows PowerShell.